# Twilio not receiving complete message

Tags: node.js, twilio, webhooks, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am sending a tiktok url to twilio webhook. But for some reasons twilio is slicing the url and not forwarding the complete url in the message.

this is the url i am sending via text: https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok/video/6807491984882765062

Twilio is forwarding this message body: https://www.tiktok.com

Even if I append some text before this. it still slice the url.

Also sometimes it doesn't receive a message altogether.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to send the message with the URL in it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that the @ sign needs to be URL Encoded when you pass it into the Twilio SDK.